# Sparse array approach to generate a Colm Mulcahy matrix

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

I wrote:

```
indmat[n_] := Module[{b, c},
  b = Transpose[{{1, 1}/2}];
  c = Transpose[{{1, -1}/2}];
  While[Min[Dimensions[b]] < n/2,
   b = ArrayFlatten[{{b, 0}, {0, b}}]];
  While[Min[Dimensions[c]] < n/2,
   c = ArrayFlatten[{{c, 0}, {0, c}}]];
  ArrayFlatten[{{b, c}}]
  ]
```

For example, with $n=8$,

```
MatrixForm[c1 = indmat[8]]
```

produces:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 &
   \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 &
   -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 &
   \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 &
   -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 &
   0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 &
   0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &
   0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &
   0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I am wondering if there is a cute Mathematica way, maybe using SparseArray, to produce the same matrices as my function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess something like this works:

```
Block[{n = 8},
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, Automatic, {2, 1}] -> 1/2, 
    Band[{2, 1}, Automatic, {2, 1}] -> 1/2, 
    Band[{1, n/2 + 1}, Automatic, {2, 1}] -> 1/2, 
    Band[{2, n/2 + 1}, Automatic, {2, 1}] -> -1/2}, {n, n}]
  ] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. And I'd like to also thank all of the other folks for the wonderful answers on this page. I am learning a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way using iteration:

```
cMMatrix[n_] := 
 Module[{f, t}, t = Flatten[ConstantArray[{1/2, 1/2, 1/2, -1/2}, n]] ;
   f = Flatten[
    Table[{{i, Floor[i/2 + 1/2]}, {i, Floor[i/2 + 1/2] + n}}, {i, 
      2 n}], 1];
  SparseArray[Thread[f -> t]] // MatrixForm]
```

Where `cMMatrix[4]` gives your standard form.
But in case it is of interest, the form can be easily expanded to higher orders, to $2n\times2n$ matrix.

```
cMMatrix[16]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case it is of interest, here is how the matrix can be computed in a factorised form

```
indmat[n_?EvenQ] := Module[{a, ix, perm, id},
  a = {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}/2;
  ix = Join[Range[1, n - 1, 2], Range[2, n, 2]]; 
  perm = SparseArray[Transpose[{ix, Range[n]}] -> 1];
  id = IdentityMatrix[n/2, SparseArray];
  KroneckerProduct[id, a].perm
  ]
```

The factorisation may be of interest in understanding your problem, even if there are equally good ways of calculating the matrix.

As an example, obtaining the inverse matrix in a similarly factored form is very simple

```
indinvmat[n_?EvenQ] := Module[{a, ix, perm, id},
  a = {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}/2;
  ix = Join[Range[1, n - 1, 2], Range[2, n, 2]]; 
  perm = SparseArray[Transpose[{ix, Range[n]}] -> 1];
  id = IdentityMatrix[n/2, SparseArray];
  Transpose[perm].KroneckerProduct[id, Inverse[a]]
  ]

indmat[8].indinvmat[8] == IdentityMatrix[8]
(* True *)
```

Comment: I seem to have subconsciously stolen your first sentence part.